# HTML syntax highligter

Tags: html, syntax-highlighting

I want to ask you for help. I need some "simply-use" HTML syntax highlighter.
I have tryed http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/ but this one doesnt support HTML5 tags and it has sliders on right side of screen no matter how big(small) content really is.

Thank you for any response.

Comment: This is a question for Google, not for StackOverflow. There are tons of syntax highlighters discoverable through Google, but you have apparently tried only one before asking here.

Answer (score 1):

## [prism.js](http://prismjs.com/)

There are many scripts for this, but I find Lea Verou`s [**prismjs**](http://prismjs.com/) library to be the easiest to use. And of course it supports HTML5!

---

To use it, just wrap your code in `pre` and `code` tags, and give them a class of `language-markup`:

```
<pre class="language-markup"><code>
  &lt;div class="example"&gt;This is automatially highlighted&lt;/div&gt;
</code></pre>
```

Here's what it'll look like:

[image]

and here' a live example: http://plnkr.co/edit/7Du1Oro4px3wsGv0BPOT?p=preview

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. But can you please give me some example how to use html syntax highlighting. I tried to find it on theirs web sites but i cant find any working example. It always take html tags as working piece of code and not highlite them.

Comment: @TomášPastorek - You have to wrap your code in `pre` & `code` tags, and give it the appropriate class. I updated the answer with this information.

Comment: Once again I thank you but i am working on some big project and i cant allow to rewrite symbols like < or > to &lt; and &gt; . T tried to use  this<![CDATA["html code"]]> to avoid this problem but unlike to other syntax highlighters in this one it does not work.